# Facebook Share With Session in DataList item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, session, datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtList" RepeatColumns="1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dtList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ..
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lblsuggestion" OnClick="lblsuggestion_Click" Text='<%# Eval("Suggestion") %>' />
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">
                <img src="Images/facebook.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>


<script>
    function fbs_click() {
        u = location.href;
        t = document.title;
        d = document.description;
        i = document.image;
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t) + '&d=' + encodeURIComponent(d) + '&i=' + encodeURIComponent(i), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I'm sharing Page-URL ,I added Facebook share button every datalist item but I cannot put session at the end of URL. How can i add it?

for instance my url now ->/help.aspx?Suggestion=9weK24GUykXJUd1GhSwwvw%3d%3d
this is always going to same page with same id without match.

how can i add the location href to session?

Answer (score 0):

If the Session exists, you can just add it to the end of the url in the template.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>&session=<%=Session["yourSession"].ToString() %>"
```

Comment: I added this link<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>&session=%=Session["QID"].ToString()" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"> and tried. Did not work. Than I tried to remove onclick event did not work again. i did't remove fbs_click and changed js url too but i think i did something wrong. Because facebook window does not open anymore.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my answer, it was missing a `<`. It should look like this: `<%=Session["yourSession"].ToString() %>`